# Eclipse Oxygen - Trouble adding JRE/JDK 9

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9

I'm getting the following error when trying to add JDK 9.
It's working with JDK 8, but not JDK 9.

Please advise.

[image: Error with JDK9]

Comment: It ***just*** came out.  Give 'em some time.  That aside...it works with Java 8 with similar paths (so the JRE home is also C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-8)? Are there differences between the Java 8 folder and the Java 9 folder?

Comment: java 8 folder is:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144

Comment: I'm using 4.7.1 and I can't add a JDK9.  :(

Answer (score 1):

Add Java 9 support for Oxygen. Read this [link](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-9-support-beta-oxygen). Java 9 stable release has launched only today. So it is not yet available in the base Oxygen package. If you are in a hurry to use Java 9 with Eclipse, you can download the support patch from market place.

Comment: The support will be integrated in to Oxygen.1 (4.7.1) which should be released in the next few days.

Comment: 4.7.1 is out and I'm facing the same issue.  Can't add a JRE/JDK 9.  :(

Comment: Out of the box support is in 4.7.1**a**, not in 4.7.1.

Answer (score 1):

The official version of eclipse that supports Java 9 is `v4.7.1a` (Notice the "a" at the end)
[The release notes are here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7.1a/)
It is available since October 11
This version also includes support for `JUnit 5`
You can [download it here as before](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I downloaded the newest Eclipse, 4.7.1, and could not add a JRE/JDK 9.

This is what I did to solve the problem:  Help -> Check for Updates.  Three updates were found.  I installed the first one, "Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers", and voilà!

I could finally add a JRE/JDK 9.  It worked via both "Add..." and "Search..." buttons.